# Deploying Django App on Heroku. While Pushing the App on heroku it gives the error

Tags: django, heroku

My Django App working well in localhost, but when I am pushing it on the Heroku by using the Git Bash terminal, the following error is shown. What is GCC?. Why these errors are showing up while deploying it on Heroku. Is there any library missing?

```
    remote:          Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
    remote:          Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
    remote:          ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
    remote:           command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qb9qpcl0/pyyaml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qb9qpcl0/pyyaml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-s5u8j4v7

remote:          In file included from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/unicodeobject.h:1026,
remote:                           from /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/Python.h:106,
remote:                           from ext/_yaml.c:4:
remote:          /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
remote:            446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
remote:                |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:          error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
remote:          ----------------------------------------
remote:          ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyyaml
remote:          Running setup.py clean for pyyaml
remote:          Building wheel for strict-rfc3339 (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for strict-rfc3339 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for strict-rfc3339: filename=strict_rfc3339-0.7-py3-none-any.whl size=18119 sha256=169b25d50478fa157faaa6b19e8714b42c42c771ca6926bb2d728a8fe20e9be8
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-wyzbci7g/wheels/25/38/74/7ec7f77ec64b2907430120931ba588b40e6e26f02d4df5be35
remote:          Building wheel for Kivy-Garden (setup.py): started
remote:          Building wheel for Kivy-Garden (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
remote:          Created wheel for Kivy-Garden: filename=Kivy_Garden-0.1.4-py3-none-any.whl size=4532 sha256=daf304aa2ab19ab3786da85313c6fa9ab5a8cdefdc3f854480c9268e519c8bc7
remote:          Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-wyzbci7g/wheels/19/1b/96/2e2906a93ec4b5d3463b0b803112feab5511a2c37dc07faed3
remote:        Successfully built anyjson css debugger django-responsive2 djangocms-typedjs doctor future mysqlclient psycopg2 PyGreSQL simplejson strict-rfc3339 Kivy-Garden
remote:        Failed to build pyyaml
remote:        Installing collected packages: anyjson, appdirs, asgiref, soupsieve, beautifulsoup4, certifi, chardet, click, colorama, css, debugger, distlib, dj-database-url, pytz, sqlparse, Django, django-appconf, django-crispy-forms, django-appointments, django-bootstrap4, django-classy-tags, django-treebeard, django-sekizai, djangocms-admin-style, django-formtools, django-cms, django-debug-toolbar, whitenoise, psycopg2, django-heroku, six, django-responsive2, Pillow, webencodings, html5lib, djangocms-text-ckeditor, djangocms-typedjs, isodate, jsonschema, pyyaml, rfc3987, simplejson, strict-rfc3339, typing-extensions, mypy-extensions, typing-inspect, doctor, docutils, hpack, hyperframe, h2, hyper, future, iso8601, idna, urllib3, requests, faunadb, filelock, MarkupSafe, Jinja2, itsdangerous, Werkzeug, Flask, gunicorn, zipp, importlib-metadata, Pygments, Kivy-Garden, Kivy, mysqlclient, pycryptodome, PyGreSQL, python-dateutil, python-decouple, virtualenv
remote:            Running setup.py install for pyyaml: started
remote:            Running setup.py install for pyyaml: finished with status 'error'
remote:            ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
remote:             command: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qb9qpcl0/pyyaml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qb9qpcl0/pyyaml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-eriq4rxn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/pyyaml
remote:                 cwd: /tmp/pip-install-qb9qpcl0/pyyaml/

remote:            /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/cpython/unicodeobject.h:446:26: note: declared here
remote:              446 | static inline Py_ssize_t _PyUnicode_get_wstr_length(PyObject *op) {
remote:                  |                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote:            error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /app/.heroku/python/bin/python -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qb9qpcl0/pyyaml/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-qb9qpcl0/pyyaml/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-eriq4rxn/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /app/.heroku/python/include/python3.9/pyyaml Check the logs for full command output.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 49aca9f2998b23aee90d2e557a72ff80fcce7091
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 49aca9f2998b23aee90d2e557a72ff80fcce7091
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to ayyalayurocare.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/ayyalayurocare.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/ayyalayurocare.git'
```

I have synced the Git Bash terminal with GitHub.I am not getting where exactly this error is coming from.

Comment: it seems that you didn't load static files load it and then try it

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration make sure you done all of it

Comment: and try to add enough data for user to understand easily

Comment: This has nothing to do with Git. You've update some code in your project; Heroku is now attempting to *compile* the code, and the compilation is failing. This means that either your code is wrong (just plain incorrect), or your requirements are wrong (your code might be correct for some version(s) of Python or other parts, but is wrong for the versions you've chosen in your requirements file).